# implicit operator List<Employee>(Company value)?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to find a way to make my foreach loops look a little cleaner.

Say I have a "company" class. This class contains several lists, such as List Employees, and List Managers.

Then, somewhere in my code, I want to loop through these lists.

I could write:

```
foreach (Employee in company.Employees) {}
foreach (Manager in company.Managers) {}
```

But I thought it would be neat to simply say:

```
foreach (Employee in company) {}
foreach (Manager in company) {}
```

But it wouldn't let me do that. So I tried to create a simple implicit conversion for company, such as:

```
static public implicit operator List<Employee>(Company value)
{
    return value.Employees;
}
static public implicit operator List<Manager>(Company value)
{
    return value.Managers;
}
```

...and surprisingly, this gave no errors, at least not on these lines.

But on the foreach statement, it gives the Error: CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Company' because 'Company' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Is there an easy way to do this, such as an implicit operator? If not, can anyone explain why it has to be so complex to do this?

Comment: I would stay far away from implicit conversions if I were you.  They rarely make the code more readable, maintainable, etc.  and they are very easy to get wrong.

Comment: `foreach (Employee in (List<Employee>) company) {};` I think this will works, but as @sstan said, try to avoid implicit casting as long as you can :). Cheers.

Comment: You say that you can write `foreach (Employee in company.Employees) { }`. No you can't - it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this.
In the code you outlined, `class Employee` and `class Manager` are distinct types, so it appears there is enough information to deduce the implicit conversion.

But recognize that they both derive from `class Object`, and possibly share other classes, such as `class Person`.   So where would that leave these expressions?

```
foreach(Object o in company) ...
foreach(Person p in company) ...
```

In those cases, the implicit conversion you intend (either to `Employees` or `Managers`) is ambiguous and unresolvable.

This is why what you propose cannot be done: because it cannot be made to work in all cases.

Comment: Well it was my hope that c# was smart enough to figure that my implicit operator for "List<Employee>(Company value)" should be used if my foreach loop is "foreach (Employee in company)"... since it obviously knows I'm trying to loop through "Employee", therefore it would search or the implicit operators, and find one to "List<Employee>", and pick it...

Comment: I get that... but my question is when you try to loop through `Object`, which implicit operator should it use?  Both the Employee and the Manager operator would qualify.

Comment: Well if I say (employee is Employee), the result is true. But if I say (new System.Object() is Employee), the result is false... so I don't see why I can't figure out that I have an implicit conversion for List<Employee> but not for List<Object>.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Company`
Your class looks like:

```
public class Company : ........
{
    ...
    
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new List<object> { Employees, Managers }.GetEnumerator();
    }
    
    ...
}
```

In workaround

```
foreach (object o in company)
{
    switch (o.GetType())
    {
        case typeof(Employee)
            //Do Stuff
            break;
        case typeof(Manager)
            //Do Stuff
            break;
    }
}
```